# Syntax refactoring in AngularJS, obtaining correct scope inheritance for data returned by $resource query call?

Tags: json, angularjs, service, scope, controllers

I am needing the scope of $scope.press to fall within the scope of ReleaseCtrl, wondering the best way to refactor the syntax to do so... I know it's a scope inheritance issue because when I try to post the same `console.log($scope.press)` below the close of the query function, I get an undefined response as opposed to the array, which properly shows up within the bounds of the "Release" query function.

```
app.service('Releases', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:3000/json', {}, {
        'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
});

app.controller("ReleaseCtrl", function (Releases, $scope){
    Releases.query(function(data, $scope){
      $scope.press = data;
      console.log($scope.press);
      for(var i=0;i<$scope.press.length;i++) {
        console.log($scope.press[i].name)
      }
    });

    $scope.loadRelease = function() {
        console.log("Loading Press Release");
    }

})
```

I imagined the Releases.query function could find its way to replace the function directly above it, but, Releases of course is undefined at that point because it has not yet been passed / injected.

I think this is fairly simple to fix, but I do not know exactly the best way to go about it.

Best regards,
Sean

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
app.service('Releases', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:3000/json', {}, {
        'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
});

app.factory ('release', function (Releases){
return Releases.query();    
})

app.controller("ReleaseCtrl", function (release, $scope){
$scope.press = release;
console.log($scope.press);
    $scope.loadRelease = function() {
        console.log("Loading Press Release");
    }
})
```

After looking around, I believed injecting with service was better practice than what I was doing earlier, so I just refactored it that way. I think re-writing what is in the service within the factory is even better. Will update when I get there.

A thing to note: Whatever you query must have more than one result. Otherwise it comes back as an object, not an array, and it does not work correctly. Maybe somebody can explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing `$scope` as a parameter to the function you pass to `.query`, and because `.query` does not call the callback with any arguments, `$scope` is probably `undefined`.

You need to use the following syntax for accessing your resources:

```
var data = Releases.query(function () {
    $scope.press = data;
    // ... Further operations with data.
});
```

[See usage note in the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource#usage_returns)